# Checking multiple checkbox with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium

I'm trying to download a spreadsheet from [this website](http://observatorios.dieese.org.br/ws/tabela/porto-alegre/regioes-do-orcamento-participativo/numero-de-estabelecimentos-formais-por-grande-setor-de-atividade-economica) using RSelenium. The first code I made was:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://observatorios.dieese.org.br/ws/tabela/porto-alegre/bairros/numero-de-estabelecimentos-formais-por-grande-setor-de-atividade-economica")
remDr$executeScript("return baixarArquivo(1)")
```

And it works! But I want download the entire data (ie. all years), so I need check the years checkbox (Filtros -> Anos). I can do this in 2 ways:

1. Selecting the checkbox 'Ano(s)', and automatically select all years
2. Selecting all years manually

I've tried both ways, but didn't work. The 'best' result I got was:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://observatorios.dieese.org.br/ws/tabela/porto-alegre/bairros/numero-de-estabelecimentos-formais-por-grande-setor-de-atividade-economica")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'anos')
remDr$executeScript("visualizar('filtros', true)")
remDr$executeScript("visualizarAnos()")
chkbox <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//input[@name='inputAno'][@type='checkbox']")
chkbox$clickElement()
remDr$executeScript("return submeter()")
remDr$executeScript("return baixarArquivo(1)")
```

But this uncheck the first year (2012) (It's my best result because it's the onlyone that do something :( )

So, the question is: how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your best result attempt, you are trying to get all the checkboxes within anos but are calling `findElement`. That is why only 2012 is being clicked, because `findElement` is returning the first element it can find that satisfies your xpath, `//input[@name='inputAno'][@type='checkbox']`.

You could fix your solution by using `findElements` like so:

```
sapply
(
    remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', "//input[@name='inputAno'][@type='checkbox']"),
    function(element){ element$clickElement() }
)
```

Alternatively, you could search for the select all checkbox with a css selector and click just that:

```
selectAll <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#anos > #alternar')
selectAll$clickElement()
```

Comment: I lost entire morning just because a 's'?! :( Thanks dude!